# Como ocultar um print após a função sleep no pycharm

Tags: python

tipo

from time import sleep

print('Loading ...')

sleep(3)

eaí ? depois do sleep, como ocultar o print 'Loading'?

porfavor, resposta mais simplificada possível, sou novato rs

ps: estou tentando fazer isto no pycharm e uso windows

Comment: Importante você editar sua [pergunta original](/q/516572/) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Não duplique perguntas, e para comentários utilize o campo apropriado abaixo da [pergunta original](/q/516572/) em vez de edições.